# How can i import a class in python file from my airflow custom operator?

Tags: python-3.x, airflow

How can i import a class in bar.py from my operator?

i have a folder structure like this

```
.
+--dags
+--libs
|  +--__init__.py
|  +--foo
|     +--__init__.py 
|     +--bar.py 
+--plugins
|  +-- foo_operators.py
```

In foo_operators.py

```
from libs.foo.bar import Client
```

but i got an error, it cannot find the class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about you move libs into dags?

```
.
+--dags
|  +--libs
|    +--__init__.py
|    +--foo
|       +--__init__.py 
|       +--bar.py 
+--plugins
|  +-- foo_operators.py
```

Comment: it works, but if i want it outside the dags folder. how can i do that?

Comment: @prideloki you can add it to your https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH